# Is there a way to avoid the boot methods in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my model I have a method which updates the index as part of the boot code:

```php
protected static function booted()
{
    static::saved(function ($mpi) {
        $mpi->updateFulltextSelf();
    });
}
```

However, I found that when I need to update many models, this causes a `Serialization Deadlock (1213)` in MySql, so I'd like to ask laravel to avoid running this method. I have tried without success:

```php
$eventDispatcher = Mpi::getEventDispatcher();
$eventDispatcher->forget('eloquent.saved: ' . Mpi::class);
```

What else works?

Comment: What is `updateFulltextSelf` ? I never saw it nor can find it in the documentation...

Comment: How about using `Mpi::withoutEvents(fn)`?

Comment: `Mpi::updateFulltextSelf()` is a command that I wrote which populates an index field.

Comment: @arvernester - I tried: `Mpi::withoutEvents(function () use (...) { $mpi->update(....); });
` but it still runs the boot command.